# Advanced sql server key combination

Tags: sql-server, key

I have an sql server address table.

The user can put either a StreetId or a NeighborhoodId or a CityID but can not put 2 of these three fields. I could restrict the user through the ui, but I would prefer to do this force this rule at the db level.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using Triggers?

Answer (score 0):

You are better of doing this in your business logic layer.

UI
^
Business logic
^
Data Access

All business rules like this can be defined in a separate business logic layer (BLL) which the UI will call and receive a message from the BLL (which can form a warning, information or an error) if the rules are not adhered to. If all the rules defined in the BLL are adhered to for the current use case, the BLL will call the data access layer (DAL) which will call the database e.g. a stored procedure with the parameters authorised by the BLL using the defined business rules.

Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I'm messing with `CHECK` constraint. But I think below code might be helpful.

Let's say we have a table `BaseTable`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BaseTable
(
    StreetId VARCHAR(50),
    NeighborhoodId VARCHAR(50),
    CityID VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Let's add a `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.BaseTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckOnlyOneColumnValue
CHECK (
(
    CASE WHEN StreetId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN NeighborhoodId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN CityID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    = 1
)
GO
```

**Test:**

These insert queries will work just fine:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BaseTable(StreetId) VALUES ('StreetId')
INSERT INTO dbo.BaseTable(NeighborhoodId) VALUES ('NeighborhoodId')
INSERT INTO dbo.BaseTable(CityID) VALUES ('CityID')
```

But these queries will fail:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BaseTable(StreetId, NeighborhoodId) 
VALUES ('StreetId', 'NeighborhoodId')

INSERT INTO dbo.BaseTable(StreetId, NeighborhoodId, CityID) 
VALUES ('StreetId', 'NeighborhoodId', 'CityID')

UPDATE dbo.BaseTable SET NeighborhoodId = 'NeighborhoodId' 
WHERE StreetId = 'StreetId'
```

Comment: The CHECK constraint is interesting. I'll check it. Thanks